Filter spans using Otel Collector
I'm using Traefik v3.0.0-rc3 with tracing.otlp enabled. The endpoint configured is a sidecar running an OpenTelemetry Collector, which is meant to change some attributes before sending the data to DataDog. As DD bills for spans and the internal spans do not provide much additional value to me I'd like to filter them.
The Otel Collector allows to easily filter those internal spans:
processors:
  filter/removeInternalSpans:
    error_mode: ignore
    traces:
      span:
        - 'kind == 1'

However, this breaks the parent relationship from the server and client spans. I haven't figured out a way in the Otel Collector to fix that relationship again. I'm aware, that I would need to configure some sliding window to look in different traces for a span of the same trace, but due to the fact that it's just a sidecar I think this window can be kept rather small.
Have you had similar issues and how did you address them?

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the collector that can fix that relationship.
Other than the TailSampling processor (that acts on the whole trace), all processors act at an individual span level, so they're unable to affect spans other than the current one.
If you don't need those spans, ever, then simply turn off the tracing for that component. Most of these kinds of systems offer something called "Pass-through", which will pass the trace context through the service, without generating it's own spans.
